# Flutter : Handling error Dio Package (404,400 etc)

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm learn searching data by ID with package **DIO** https://pub.dev/packages/dio, my problem is every time I'm type wrong keyword search, the app suddenly crash with debug message **404 Not Found**.

[image]

I know data not found because I'm type wrong keyword, but I'm already handle this with this code

```
Widget _searchKeywordMahasiswa() {
    return FutureBuilder<List<Mosque>>(
      future: api.getMahasiswaById(_searchText),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Text(snapshot.data[index].id);
              },
            ),
          );
        } else if (!snapshot.data) { <<<<<< IN THIS LINE
          return Center(
            child: Icon(
              Icons.sentiment_very_dissatisfied,
              size: 150.0,
            ),
          );
        }
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
      },
    );
    // return CircularProgressIndicator();
  }
```

```
Future<List<Mosque>> getMahasiswaById(String id) async{
    try {
      var apiRespon = await dio.get('${Urls.BASE_API_URL}/mahasiswa/get/id/$id');
      var apiResponJson = apiRespon.data;
      print(apiResponJson);
      return (apiResponJson['data'] as List).map((p)=>Mosque.fromJson(p)).toList();

    }on DioError catch (e) { <<<<< IN THIS LINE
      if(e.response.statusCode == 404){
        print(e.response.statusCode);
      }else{
        print(e.message);
        print(e.request);
      }
    }
  }
```

> In same case my App crash too if i'm get error **400 Bad Request** And i'm already handle this error but not works.

Can you Help Me With This?

Comment: please print content of this variable ${Urls.BASE_API_URL}/mahasiswa/get/id/$id and paste it to your browser. and "add comment" to allow me trace when you finish this step. thanks.

Comment: @chunhunghan When i paste `http://192.168.43.159/wpu-rest-server/apii/mahasiswa/get/ID/$id` in browser. show me `An Error Was Encountered. The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.`

Comment: please change $id to a real exist id, such as 123 or string and do again.

Comment: @chunhunghan If i paste `http://192.168.43.159/wpu-rest-server/apii/mahasiswa/get/id/5` Show me data by id 5

Comment: how about just throw the error on catch? 
and add snapshot.hasError? on if else statement on futurebuilder

Answer (score 69, accepted):

```
 var response = await dio.delete(
          url,
          data: postData,
          options: Options(
            followRedirects: false,
            validateStatus: (status) {
              return status < 500;
            },
            headers: headers,
          ),
        );
```

please use the code below bro,

add followRedirects, validateStatus to your code.

Comment: Not sure this is the correct way. But bro! it worked for me.

Comment: This was a tricky answer, and absolutely work, but not in a pro way, I've just post an answer below this question that recommend by Dio itself. Hope you accept it.

Comment: Not sure why, but when using `validateStatus` the 304 cache feature doesn't work anymore...

Answer (score 27):

remove 'on DioError' - unfortunately there are some errors (404's, 500s...) that Dio wont't process and won't catch - had similar problem in my app.
Then change code to posted below or use some other logic to 'catch'em all' ;)

```
} catch (e) {

    if (e is DioError) {
    //handle DioError here by error type or by error code

    } else {
    ...
    }
 //return empty list (you can also return custom error to be handled by Future Builder)
}
```

by the way you should properly handle Future Builder states: `snapshot.hasData`, empty data and `snapshot.hasError` in your future builder to prevent future crashes

Comment: please can you give example what i can do in **if** and **else** statement ?
what i can insert in **if** statement `return null` and in **else** statement i'm insert `return true` ? or what ? Thank's

Comment: i'm already follow your code , my app still crash if i type wrong keyword.

Comment: and make sure you declare proper ulr - 404 means not found. unfortunately I cannot check your code in AndroidStudio at the moment

Comment: Can you check my answer , why if i use http.get my code it's Work, but in **DIO** it's crash ? 
i try replace `http.get` with `dio.get` and still facing error ?

Comment: the information you've provided is not enough... 
if its 400 you're getting, it menas that teheres something wrong with your api call (url, body, headers etc)  - double/triple check it

Comment: this is old, but if you're reading this, the response is partially wrong: Dio handles 4xx and 5xx as expected - It's paramount that to work, you pass in the options validate Status function, before the call. like: `validateStatus: (status) => status! < 400,` that way status will be true (and no errors will be thrown) for any response code lower than 400.

Answer (score 19):

Error is with this URL string pattern `${Urls.BASE_API_URL}/mahasiswa/get/id/$id`

you can not use . operator and access the inner value from any object inside "". You can store the exact url in other variable and use it in that line. Code should be as follows.

```
Future<List<Mosque>> getMahasiswaById(String id) async{
try {
  var baseURL = Urls.BASE_API_URL;
  var apiRespon = await dio.get('${baseURL}/mahasiswa/get/id/$id');
  var apiResponJson = apiRespon.data;
  print(apiResponJson);
  return (apiResponJson['data'] as List).map((p)=>Mosque.fromJson(p)).toList();

}on DioError catch (e) { <<<<< IN THIS LINE
  if(e.response.statusCode == 404){
    print(e.response.statusCode);
  }else{
    print(e.message);
    print(e.request);
  }
}
}
```

============ UPDATE ============

You can use `.` operator as follows,

```
var apiRespon = await dio.get('${Urls.BASE_API_URL}/mahasiswa/get/id/$id');
```

Comment: Can you check my answer , why if i use http.get my code it's Work, but in **DIO** it's crash ? 
i try replace `http.get` with `dio.get` and still facing error ?

Comment: . operator can be used inside ''

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem it was just changing my interceptor that worked

```
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';

class CustomInterceptor extends Interceptor {
  @override
  void onRequest(RequestOptions options, RequestInterceptorHandler handler) async {
    print("onRequest");
    return super.onRequest(options, handler);
  }

  @override
  Future onResponse(Response response, ResponseInterceptorHandler handler) {
    print("onResponse");
    return null;
  }

  @override
  Future onError(DioError err, ErrorInterceptorHandler handler) async {
    print("onError: ${err.response.statusCode}");
    return handler.next(err);  // <--- THE TIP IS HERE
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I also had the similar type problem.

First, try to run the project from command prompt with `flutter run` see if there is occurring any problem or not.

If the command prompt is showing no problem & your app is running smoothly then you have to check the IDE. If you are using VSCode then switch to Debug is side bar, see which options are ticked in Breakpoint section. If `All Exceptions` is ticked then the debugger will pause on every exception. Uncheck both `All Exceptions` & `Uncaught Exceptions` then try refresh restart.

Hope this will solve your problem.

[image: Breakpoint Section Image]

Answer (score 4):

You can manage timeout exception using `DioClient`:

There are two way, declaring customized `Option` then assign to the `Dio` or directly assign below `option` to it, but I prefer to separate these type of `Option` for oriented need.
You can set a condition to get all problems except 400 (success) response, but you have to aware of **Connection Timeout**, so here a integrated in Dio way:

```
class YourRepositary {
  Dio dioClient;

  YourRepositary() {
    if (dioClient == null) {
      BaseOptions options = new BaseOptions(
          baseUrl: "YOUR_APIs_BASE_URL",
          receiveDataWhenStatusError: true,
          connectTimeout: 30000, // 30 seconds
          receiveTimeout: 30000 // 30 seconds
          );

      dioClient = new Dio(options);
    }
  }

  Future<ProductResponseModel> getProduct(var productRequestInputDto) async {
    try {
      Response response = await dio.post("/api/getProduct", data: productRequestInputDto);
      final ProductResponseModel _productModel = ProductResponseModel.fromJson(response.data);
      return _productModel ;
    } on DioError  catch (ex) {
      if(ex.type == DioErrorType.CONNECT_TIMEOUT){
        throw Exception("Connection Timeout Exception");
      }
      throw Exception(ex.message);
    }
  }

}
```

At the end, below example demonstrate how you handle Timeout exception or even handled by your backend 500 error in API call:

```
void getProduct(){
 ProductRequestInputDto productRequest = new ProductRequestInputDto(productId: "666");

        var requestBody = jsonEncode(loginRequest);
        debugPrint("Request Data : $requestBody");

        _apiRepositary.getProduct(requestBody).then((response){
          debugPrint("Login Success $response");
          //manage your response here 
         },
          onError: (exception){
              //Handle exception message
            if(exception.message != null ){
              debugPrint(exception.message); // Here you get : "Connection  Timeout Exception" or even handled 500 errors on your backend.
            }
          },
        );
}
```

To conclusion, it's all about `receiveDataWhenStatusError: true`, in the option of Dio.

Comment: I looked for your comment after reading your comment on the selected solution. For a 400 response code this did not work for me while `validateStatus` did. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Found a solution. This code worked for me.

```
try {
  Dio dio = Dio();
  var res = await dio.download(
    url + 'fg',
    savePath.path + "/filename.bin",
    onReceiveProgress: (count, total) {
      progress(count, total);
    },
  );
} on DioError catch (e) {
  if (e.type == DioErrorType.response) {
    print('catched');
    return;
  }
  if (e.type == DioErrorType.connectTimeout) {
    print('check your connection');
    return;
  }

  if (e.type == DioErrorType.receiveTimeout) {
    print('unable to connect to the server');
    return;
  }

  if (e.type == DioErrorType.other) {
    print('Something went wrong');
    return;
  }
  print(e);
} catch (e) {
  print(e);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  dynamic _decodeErrorResponse(dynamic e) {
    dynamic data = {"statusCode": -1, "message": "Unknown Error"};
    if (e is DioError) {
      if (e.type == DioErrorType.response) {
        final response = e.response;
        try {
          if (response != null && response.data != null) {
            final Map responseData =
                json.decode(response.data as String) as Map;
            data["message"] = responseData['message'] as String;
            data["statusCode"] = response.statusCode;
          }
        } catch (e) {
          data["message"] = "Internal Error Catch";
        }
      } else if (e.type == DioErrorType.connectTimeout ||
          e.type == DioErrorType.receiveTimeout ||
          e.type == DioErrorType.sendTimeout) {
        data["message"] = "Request timeout";
        data["statusCode"] = 408;
      } else if (e.error is SocketException) {
        data["message"] = "No Internet Connection!";
      }
    }
    return data;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and this is how I solved it.

```
} catch (exception) {
      if (exception.runtimeType == DioError) {
        var dioException = exception as DioError;
        
        return dioException.response!; // Do something with response
      }

      rethrow; // or do something else with response
    }
}
```

It's similar to some of the answers above, but I had to use `if(exception.runtimeType == DioError)` to check the type of the exception, as `if(exception is DioError)` didn't seem to work for me.

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

The selected answer is working perfectly fine. But if someone still getting an error after adding those lines. You can try this one.

Add content type to the field.

```
dio.FormData formData = dio.FormData.fromMap({
      "file": await dio.MultipartFile.fromFile(
        file.path,
        filename: fileName,
        contentType: MediaType('audio', 'mp4'),
      ),
```