# Why doesn't my method work in DioError catch in Flutter/Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am making a request to my database  like this:

```dart
//Airtable (find a record)
  void airtableFind() async {
    try {
      final response = await Dio().get(
        'https://api.airtable.com/v0/'+projectBase+'/'+recordName,
        queryParameters: {
          'filterByFormula': 'SEARCH('+'"'+username+'"'+',{Name})' // Searches the value 'Cactus' in the {'Short description'} field.
        },
        options: Options(
          contentType: 'Application/json',
          headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer'+' '+apiKey,
            'Accept': 'Application/json',
          },
        ),
      );

      // TODO: Whatever you want to do with the response. A good practice is to transform it into models and than work with them
      // print(response);
      // print(response.data['records'][0]['id']);
      idString = response.data['records'][0]['id'];
      // if (idString.isNotEmpty) (
      //     showInvalidUsernameDialog(context)
      //     // TODO: Need to inform about success
      // );

    } on DioError catch (e) {
      // TODO: Error handling
      if (e.response != null) {
        // print(e.response.data);
        print(e);
        showInvalidUsernameDialog(context);

      } else {
        // print(e.request);
        print(e.message);
        showInvalidUsernameDialog(context);
      }
    }
  }
```

If my user enters the correct word (username), then everything works correctly. But there is always a risk that a person is mistaken. And I want to indicate this with the `showInvalidUsernameDialog(context);` dialog box, but for some reason it does not pop up.

I see errors in the console:

```
I/flutter(4484): DioError [DioErrorType.response]: Http status error [422]
I/flutter ( 4484): Source stack:
I/flutter(4484): #0 DioMixin.fetch(package:dio/src/dio_mixin.dart:488:35)
I/flutter ( 4484): #1 DioMixin.request (package:dio/src/dio_mixin.dart:483:12)
I/flutter ( 4484): #2 DioMixin.patch (package:dio/src/dio_mixin.dart:249:12)
I/flutter(4484): #3 _RouteState.airtableUpdate(package:example/main.dart:1498:36)
I/flutter ( 4484): #4 _RouteState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:example/main.dart:1617:13)
I/flutter ( 4484): #5 _RouteState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:example/main.dart:1612:24)
I/flutter(4484): #6 EditableTextState._finalizeEditing (package:flutter/src/widgets/editable_text.dart:2148:18)
I/flutter(4484): #7 EditableTextState.performAction(package:flutter/src/widgets/editable_text.dart:1999:9)
I/flutter(4484): #8 TextInput._handleTextInputInvocation(package:flutter/src/services/text_input.dart:1746:37)
I/flutter ( 4484): #9 MethodChannel._handleAsMethodCall (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:404:55)
I/flutter ( 4484): #10 MethodChannel.setMethodCallHandler.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/services/platform_chan
E/flutter ( 4484): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0
E/flutter ( 4484): #0 List.[] (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:264:36)
E/flutter ( 4484): #1 _RouteState.airtableFind (package:example/main.dart:1473:42)
E/flutter ( 4484): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 4484):
```

And that's to be expected, since I'm deliberately entering the wrong username. But I want to get not only a list of errors in the console, but also a dialog box. Why doesn't it appear?

The dialog box call method is correct. I put it in the part of the code that fires when the username is valid. It appears exactly as intended.

But why doesn't this method work in this part of the code?

```dart
on DioError catch (e) {
      // TODO: Error handling
      if (e.response != null) {
        // print(e.response.data);
        print(e);
        showInvalidUsernameDialog(context);

      } else {
        // print(e.request);
        print(e.message);
        showInvalidUsernameDialog(context);
      }
```

And how can I make this dialog appear in case of an error?

**Edit 1**. `_RouteState.airtableFind (package:example/main.dart:1473:42)` is referring to `idString = response.data['records'][0]['id'];`. This happens when my user enters their login incorrectly.

Comment: Which line is `_RouteState.airtableFind (package:example/main.dart:1473:42)` referring to?  Can you provide a minimal, reproducible example?

Comment: I added ```Edit 1``` if that's enough.

Comment: The stack trace from your console is possibly a red herring. [`DioError.toString`](https://pub.dev/documentation/dio/latest/dio/DioError/toString.html) might include the stack trace, so there probably is not actually an uncaught exception.  If `showInvalidUsernameDialog` isn't working from within the `catch` block, there might be something wrong with `showInvalidUsernameDialog`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use catch directly and check if its of type DioError. This is a known behaviour.. Its not catching 400 or 500 errors

https://github.com/flutterchina/dio/issues/1198

```
try{

}catch(e){
 print(e.toString()); 
}
```

or

```
try{
}catch(e){
 if(e is DioError)
 {
 }
}
```

Comment: The OP showed a stack trace that clearly shows a `DioError`, and [using unqualified `catch (e)` clauses is a bad idea](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.6/dart-async/Stream-class.html) since it will catch lots of things that shouldn't be caught (including `Error`s such as `AssertionError`).

Comment: The updated answer still swallows everything that isn't a `DioError`, which is bad.  And, as mentioned, the stack trace clearly shows that a `DioError` *is* thrown.

Comment: I don't know why, but your original version shows my popup, while the edited version ignores it. In principle, I am completely satisfied with this. But if ```jamesdlin``` has a different solution, then I won't close this question just yet.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57455741/flutter-handling-error-dio-package-404-400-etc @jamesdlin please check this out.. also the link you have added in comment is taking me to streams.

Comment: Do you have any idea why the ```if(e is DioError)``` variant doesn't work in my case?

Comment: Not sure but its definitely because the exception caught is not of type DioError. If you print the exception what do you get?

Comment: When I use ```print(e.toString());```, I see the same entries in the console. However, your original version works fine and shows my popup. So it's more of a matter of curiosity. Maybe I'll come back to this later if it becomes a problem. At the moment everything is fine. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Oops, I pasted the wrong link in my earlier comment.  It should have been: [AVOID catches without on clauses](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/usage#avoid-catches-without-on-clauses).